# Mock doctrine param converter when testing Symfony controller

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony

I am currently writing some tests for my Symfony controllers. I use Doctrine param converter in it and I fail to find a way to mock it in my test suite !

My controller looks like :

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 * @Route("/troops/{troop_id}/membership-requests/{id}/accept", name="accept_membership_request", methods={"POST"})
 * @param \AppBundle\Controller\MembershipRequest $membershipRequest
 */
public function acceptMembershipRequest(MembershipRequest $membershipRequest) {
    $troop = $membershipRequest->getTroop();
    if($this->get('kilix_abac.security')->enforce('troop_leadership', $this->getUser(), $troop) !== true) {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('troops.access_denied');
    }
    $this->get('medievistes.troop.membership_request_manager')->acceptMembershipRequest($membershipRequest);
    return new JsonResponse([
        'redirection_url' => $this->generateUrl('troop_dashboard', ['id' => $membershipRequest->getTroop()->getId()])
    ]);
}
```

The associated test method is

```
public function testAcceptMembershipRequest() {
    $client = $this->createLoggedClient();
    $client->getContainer()->set('medievistes.troop.membership_request_manager', $this->getMembershipRequestManagerMock());
    $client->getContainer()->set('kilix_abac.security', $this->getKilixAbacMock());
    $client->request('POST', '/troops/1/membership-requests/1/accept');

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    $this->assertJson($client->getResponse()->getContent());
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('redirection_url', json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), true));
}
```

I obviously get a 404 response instead of the expected 200, due to the fact that a SQL query is performed on an empty test database. I know that I can use fixtures, I used it and I still use it for my repository tests, but I'd like to avoid using it in this context.

If there is a way to mock this converter, I'd be glad to hear about it !

Thanks community !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock the param convert that is responsible for searching those information in database. So you can create a mock service responsible for searching objects within database, which is located under `sensio_framework_extra.converter.doctrine.orm`. Or you can just change the class parameter value for your class name.

```
sensio_framework_extra.converter.doctrine.class
```

Of course this should before you post the request the same way as you are doing for request_membership_manager and security:

```
$client->getContainer()->set(
    'sensio_framework_extra.converter.doctrine.orm', 
    $this->getDoctrineConvertMock()
);
```

Comment: For a reason I don't know, when I mock this class, the param converter manager picks another. So the mock is uneffective ! But when mocking the param converter manager itself, it works like intended, you just have to register a callback which will populate the data in the request attributes yourself ! I will put the final code in my question as an edit, but I give you the right answer :D ! Thanks you :) !

Comment: I'm sorry, I know this is a bit old question but I don't see the implementation of this method $this->getMembershipRequestManagerMock(). I'm having issues mocking a param converter and I will appreciate if you could post the implementation of this method. Thanks